# Intuition about Schemes over a Fixed Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

The following is an old MO question that I believe is probably not appropriate for MO currently.

https://mathoverflow.net/a/7474/104812

In particular, I would like to resurrect this question, and would also like an explanation similar to the answer in the permalink above.

Can anybody help clear this up?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: I understand that $\mathbb{C}$ is a scheme over $\mathbb{Q}$, and that fiber products gives a notion of extension of scalars for schemes. My question is roughly what this means when instead of dealing with fields and thinking of fields as schemes over other fields, we have the more general setting of a scheme over another scheme. I don't have an intuition for 'coefficients in a scheme' and I don't even know if that makes sense.

Comment: In general, how should I think about the geometric meaning of a scheme over another scheme?

Comment: The most common sense of "scheme $X$ over a scheme $S$" means that $X$ is the total space of a family of schemes parametrized by $S$. For this to be in any way useful one should also assume $X$ flat over $S$. For morphisms like $Spec(\mathbb C) \to Spec(\mathbb Q)$, which topologically is the identity map on a point but which corresponds to the field extension on the level of sheaves of rings, you have to accept that one-point schemes are a good bit more complicated than one-point spaces...

Comment: ...In the category of schemes one has a morphism $f$ from a point to a point such that the automorphism group of $f$ is the Galois group of any given field extension.